# Javascript: use map function in array from last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Is there any way I can use map function from the last element of array not first one? I want to map my array from the last one.

Comment: Invert the array, map, then invert the result array.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `array.reverse().map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) instead of reversing the array first. It starts the iteration from the right side, without mutating the array.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3],
    result = data.reduceRight((r, a) => r.concat(a * 2), []);

console.log(result);
```